# Animate list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a really simple jQuery problem (I guess). But im totally new to jQuery and having a hard time to solve this.

i have a list

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Every 5 secs i would like to rotate this. So every item moves up (the first one gets to the last place).

Which is the easiest way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("ul").append( $("ul li:first") );
}, 5000);
```

You should give the `<ul>` an ID to make it unambiguous. [See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/aCfmS/2/)

Comment: This will only run once though.

Comment: @Supr No, it will run every 5 seconds. (Whoops, you were right, I meant to use `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`. Fixed, thanks.)

Comment: `detach()` is not needed here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah. Makes sense. Fixed that, too.

Comment: When jQuery is inserting something into the DOM that is already in the DOM, it automatically gets removed from the previous location.  See the jsFiddle demo in my answer that doesn't have the `.detach()`.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `ul` an id like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>​
```

Then, you can use this jQuery with `setTimeout()`:

```
var list$ = $("#myList");
function rotateList() {
    list$.find("li:first").appendTo(list$);
    setTimeout(rotateList, 5000);
}

rotateList();
```

Demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KVzXa/ (running every 1 second for purposes of the demo).

Or, it could also be done with `setInterval()` like this:

```
var list$ = $("#myList");
setInterval(function() {
    list$.find("li:first").appendTo(list$);
}, 5000);
```

I chose to save a little CPU in both implementations by caching $("#myList") rather than rerunning it on every rotation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get a nice animation is with the [Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) plugin for jQuery:

It would look like this:

```
var lis = $('ul.list').children('li').get();

$('ul.list').quicksand($('<ul>').append(lis).children());

setInterval(function(){
    lis.push(lis.shift());
    $('ul.list').quicksand($('<ul>').append(lis).children());
}, 5000);
```

You will also need to add a "data-id" attribute to your `li`'s so Quicksand can animate them nicely:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li data-id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li data-id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li data-id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li data-id="item4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/EmZJg/1/)
​

Answer (score 0):

```
function rotate(){
    $('li').first().detach().appendTo($('ul'));
    setTimeout(rotate, 1000); 
}

rotate();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yXRpJ/

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
function menu() {
    $menu = $('#menu');
    $first = $menu.find("li").first();
    $first.animate({marginTop:-1 * $first.height()}, 1000, 'linear', function () {
        $menu.append($first);
        $first.attr('style', '');
    });
}
setInterval("menu()", 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4UhX/